# Look at the bytes in a directory?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems

I would like to see what the actual contents of a directory file are (not the files that are   contained within that directory).

Specifically I would like to be able to do something like:

```
od -c .
```

I know this works (used to work?) on unix, as it is shown on page 59 of 'The Unix Programming Environment'

Yet when I attempt on my version of Arch Linux I get the following:

```
read error: Is a directory
```

Is there another command I should be using to inspect the bytes of a directory?

Comment: IIRC in the book "Linux Systems Programming", it is explained that the Linux kernel does not allow direct reads on directories.

Comment: @jordanm that would explain my problem. I shall read into it more from that book. Thanks